# v.voronoi.skeleton error

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-processing, skeleton

Recently, I was looking for way to skeletonize buffer and besides solution with PostGIS and Postegre solutions there is algortihm `v.voronoi.skeleton`. I have tried to use it with different road/rail buffers as described in [this tutorial](http://www.dts.put.poznan.pl/wp-content/uploads/QGIS/v_voronoi_skeleton_i_r_thin.pdf) (unfortunatelly in polish, though the best source I got).

Despite following instructions with different parametres and input layers I always get error with output and no layer is created.

```
2019-07-01T20:50:58     WARNING    Duplicate output OUTPUT_HTML_FILE registered for alg build_generic_plot
2019-07-01T20:50:58     WARNING    Duplicate output OUTPUT_JSON_FILE registered for alg build_generic_plot
```

Comment: Which GRASS GIS do you use? There was recently a bugfix in v.voronoi (used here): https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/pull/26

Comment: QGIS 3.8.0 with GRASS 7.6.1, though the problem does noe seem to be about otuput, since there is none - error is printed without any new layer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the GRASS module `v.voronoi`, with the `-s` option to create a voronoi diagram around polygons.  There is an [open issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15282) with this module.

I suggest that you first create centroids, and then try to run v.`voronoi` around those centroid points.